# Compute $E\left((B_t−1)^2\int ^t_0(B_s+1)^2 dB_s\right)$, where $(B_t)$ is a standard Brownian motion

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Compute $E((B_t−1)^2\int ^t_0(B_s+1)^2 dB_s)$ for $t≥0$ given that $(B_t)_{t≥0}$ is a Standard Brownian Motion.

Presume we will need to compute $E((B_t+B_s)-(B_s-1))^2$ to get some independent terms but really stuck on what to do with the integral part. Thanks for any help with this question.

Comment: @Did could you clarify why $E(B_{t}X_{t})=E(\int_0^tY_{s}ds)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the processes $$X_t=\int ^t_0Y_s dB_s\qquad Y_t=(B_t+1)^2$$ By repeated applications of [Itô isometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_isometry), one gets:

- $E(X_t)=0$
- $B_tX_t=\displaystyle\int_0^tdB_s\cdot\int ^t_0Y_sdB_s$ hence $$E(B_tX_t)=E\left(\int_0^tY_s ds\right)=\int_0^tE(Y_s)ds$$
- $(B_t^2-t)X_t=\displaystyle\int_0^t2B_sdB_s\cdot\int ^t_0Y_sdB_s$ hence $$E((B_t^2-t)X_t)=E\left(\int_0^t2B_sY_s ds\right)=2\int_0^tE(B_sY_s)ds$$

Finally, if one can compute $E(Y_t)$ and $E(B_tY_t)$, the proof is complete. Can you?

Comment: Like at every other step, use Itô isometry, based on the fact that $$d\langle B,B\rangle_t=dt$$ hence, for every suitable processes $(u_t)$ and $(v_t)$, $$E\left(\int_0^tu_sdB_s\cdot\int_0^tv_sdB_s\right)=E\left(\int_0^tu_sv_sds\right)$$

Comment: ((This is answering a comment formerly here but now on main, by the OP.))

Comment: ah I get it now, thank you!